# How to create a filter control using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a filter control, however it doesn't work properly yet.

```
<div class="panel-filter-wrapper"><div class="panel-filter" data-filter-property="">
    <div class="panel-selected-filter">
        <span class="selected-filter-name">All</span>
        <span class="caret caret-down"></span>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li data-value="*" data-param="role" class="selected">All</li>
        <li data-value="admin" data-param="role" class="">Admins</li>
        <li data-value="client" data-param="role">Clients</li>
        <li data-value="agent" data-param="role">Agents</li> 
    </ul>
```

The css code:

```
.panel-filter-wrapper {
 display: inline-block;
}
.panel-filter {
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
color: #999;
}
.panel-filter .panel-selected-filter {
padding: 2px 19px 2px 10px;
border: 1px solid transparent;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
.panel-filter:hover,
.panel-filter.active {
color: #444;
}
.panel-filter:hover .panel-selected-filter,
.panel-filter.active .panel-selected-filter {
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 background: #fff;
}
.panel-filter:hover .caret,
.panel-filter.active .caret {
 display: inline-block;
}
.panel-filter.active .panel-selected-filter {
 border-bottom-width: 0;
}
.panel-filter.active ul {
display: block;
}
.panel-filter ul {
list-style: none;
display: none;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
top: 24px;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
min-width: 100%;
z-index: 0;
background: #fff;
font-size: 13px;
border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.panel-filter li {
padding: 5px 15px;
white-space: nowrap;
color: #333;
}
.panel-filter li:first-child {
border-top: none;
}
.panel-filter li:hover {
background-color: #f2f4f8 !important;
color: #181a1c;
}
.panel-filter li.selected {
font-weight: bold;
}
.panel-filter .caret {
display: none;
position: absolute;
right: 5px;
top: 9px;
}

.caret {
display: inline-block;
width: 0;
height: 0;
vertical-align: top;
border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
border-top: 4px solid transparent;
border-right: 4px solid transparent;
border-left: 4px solid black;
content: "";
}
.caret,
.caret-down {
border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
border-top: 4px solid black;
border-right: 4px solid transparent;
border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

The code example is on [JSfiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/KTGqA/).
The promlem is that the jquery does not handle the click event and the items list does not display. The control should looks (behave) like:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I don't see any jquery code here.

Comment: Well actually the jquery code is the question. How can I add it to handle this event? Thank you.

Comment: Let's see the jquery code it's not in your jsfiddle as well.

Comment: I need to add something like $("div.panel-selected-filter").click(function () {$(this).something here}); to make it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, It should work as expected. Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/XWW6G/1/).

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".panel-selected-filter").click(function() { // show the dropdown list
         $('.panel-filter > ul').show();
     });

     $('.panel-filter > ul > li').click(function() {  // select and hide the the list
         $('.selected-filter-name').text($(this).text());
         $('.panel-filter > ul').hide();
     });

     $(document).click(function(e){           // hide list if clicked outside
         if($(e.target).is('.panel-selected-filter, .panel-selected-filter *'))return;
             $('.panel-filter > ul').hide();
     });
});
```

And I have add padding: 0px; in your css class, like this:

**CSS:**

```
.panel-filter ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;          /* added to align li's to the left*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: With this code, my caret disappears. And I can not select the element from the list.

Comment: I have edited the jQuery code for selecting the item and display as the selected item. The caret may be disappears due to css. It was also not in the Fiddle provided by you.

Comment: I have added a symbol to check the caret. <span class="caret caret-down">^</span>. This is working fine.

Comment: The css code for the caret is here in SoF css code-example at the bottom. Most probably I have deleted it accidently from jsfiddle. Your code works almost fine however, how to cancel the selection by clicking the empty space? I mean I can click the control, and the list appears, then I may want to click outside the list to make it disappear (without selecting an element). Now it doesn't disappear. Here is updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KTGqA/3/

Comment: you can add .blur() event on the '.panel-filter > ul > li' and hide the 'ul'. I have not tried this with your code, but it shuld work.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added the code for hiding the list if clicked outside. .blur() and .focusout() do only work with A, AREA, BUTTON, INPUT, LABEL, SELECT, TEXTAREA elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

    function showFileter()
    {

        var ul = document.getElementById('FilterOption');
        ul.style.display = (ul.style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none";
    }

</script>

<div class="panel-filter-wrapper"><div class="panel-filter" data-filter-property="">
    <div class="panel-selected-filter" onClick='showFileter()'>
        <span class="selected-filter-name">All</span>
        <span class="caret caret-down"></span>
    <ul id="FilterOption" style='display:none;padding:0;'>
        <li data-value="*" data-param="role" class="selected">All</li>
        <li data-value="admin" data-param="role" class="">Admins</li>
        <li data-value="client" data-param="role">Clients</li>
        <li data-value="agent" data-param="role">Agents</li> 
    </ul>
    </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: It is not exactly what I want. The menu must appear on click! Not on hover.